# Generating a random List() of List(List(Doubles))

Tags: scala, random, immutability

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a list of random doubles through the range -50 to 50, with the length of list being 20. (so 20 elements of random doubles ranging from -50 to 50).

I then want to create a fixed number (could be any number, we'll say 3 for now) of List[List[Double]] with that randomized double list. I read up on the Random doc but it is still very confusing to me. This is what I currently have:

```
 val length: Int = 20
 val doubles: List[Double] = List()
 val listOf: List[List[Double]] = List(List())
 val rand = new Random()
```

Essentially, let's say I do generate a list of 20 elements with random doubles ranging from -50 to 50. I then want to generate a random number of lists that include the randomized
list of doubles.
Ex:

```
val doubles: List[Double] = List(-29.3,46.8,-17.0,9.2,1.4) // in this case, doubles has a length of 5)
val listOf: List[List[Double]] = List(List(-29.3,46.8,-17.0,9.2,1.4),List(-5.0,3.4,31.5,29.0,-41.3)) // in this case, the inner lists have a length of 5, and the fixed number is
//2 because listOf has a length of 2
```

I am also looking to approach this problem with no mutability. How can I generate a random list of doubles with the above specs, and then generate a list of random lists?

Comment: There can be duplicate element between each list or not? There can be duplicate elements between lists or not? - Also, I am a bit confused you want a  list of lists of random numbers, or you want a list of random lists of random numbers?

Comment: 1. There cannot be any duplicate elements. 2. To be more clear, it would make more sense to generate a list of random lists of random numbers, but my original thought process was to have one list dedicated to the random doubles, and then implement that into the List of lists, although that may require mutability. But yes, a list of random lists of random numbers is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The straight forward answer is simply:

```
import scala.util.Random

List.fill(3)(List.fill(20)(Random.between(-50.0, 50.0)))
```

The likelihood of repeating any of the random `Double`s is extremely small, but if you absolutely *must* guarantee uniqueness, without mutation, then here's one rather inefficient solution.

```
import scala.util.Random

def isDistinct(lld: List[List[Double]]):Boolean =
  lld.flatten.foldLeft((true, Set.empty[Double])){
    case ((res, seen), dbl) => (res && !seen(dbl), seen+dbl)
  }._1

LazyList.continually {
  val llr = List.fill(3)(List.fill(20)(Random.between(-50.0, 50.0)))
  Option.when(isDistinct(llr))(llr)
}.flatten.head
```

Also worth noting: `between()` is inclusive at the bottom (so `-50.0` is unlikely but possible) and exclusive at the top (so exactly `50.0` shouldn't be possible).

---

**Scala 2.12.x translation**

```
def isDistinct(. . .  //same

val rng = new scala.util.Random

Stream.continually {                                                   
  val llr = List.fill(3)(List.fill(20)(rng.nextDouble * 100 - 50))
  if (isDistinct(llr)) Some(llr) else None
}.flatten.head
```

Comment: It seems that I forgot to mention I am on Scala 2.12.12. between is not in the Random library until after 2.13.